# Sub Domain is like Subfolder of website in Url Rewriting in IIS 7

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, url-rewriting

I have subdomain as ex. abc.apple.com. Link of this sub domain is on apple.com. Now any one click on it than it will redirect to abc.apple.com but url will look like apple.com/abc/ . I have using.NET 3.5 for development and IIS 7 for web server. Please help me

Comment: may be you will have to create asp.net routing.. and then create your own route handler that will permanent redirect to your domain.. http://blog.abodit.com/2010/04/a-simple-redirect-route-handler-for-asp-net-3-5-routing/

Comment: Thank you for response. I think link not working well. Please give alternate link if you have

Answer (score 0):

You will have to have a look at ASP.Net routing.. have a look at IRouteHandler at MSDN then go through the article mentioned below.

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/12/15/redirect-routes-and-other-fun-with-routing-and-lambdas.aspx

this is a very good example to permanent redirect urls..